# Google maps api restyle map feature popup

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In google maps api is it possible to style popup of a map feature (i.e. park)
http://screencast.com/t/aSMJBOgUXm

p.s. I'm aware it is possible to hide park icon:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#StyledMapElements

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no simple way for doing this.

You can use the places library, draw your own markers for the features you are interested in, and set the info window content (and style) accordingly.

Places Library: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

See the top rated answer to this question: [Google Maps API v3 Point of Interest with Custom Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269231/google-maps-api-v3-point-of-interest-with-custom-icons)

You could use the same idea to adapt the content of the info window.

Comment: thanks, but Im already creating custom markers for features I'm interested. But also wanted to control google's features. Is it possible to just block google pop-up for features?