# How can I enable icons for tourist attractions from google maps on my site?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

[image: Photo with red markers]

I refer to this red icons on the map who show restaurants, churches, museums etc.

Comment: Did OP ask how he should add his business?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These *tourist attractions* as you named them are called POI (point of interest) attractions. Museums and other touristic attractions fall within the `poi.attraction` feature type: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType

By default all feature types are shown on the map. Only the icons are different from what you see on maps.google.com.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/4shetfmL/)</kbd>

If you are looking for a solution to allow users to search your map and to customize the icons, you can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11269912/1238965

Hope this helps.