# Google Maps POI icons on Android and iOS customization

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I can't find any way to customize icons for POIs on Google Maps for Android and iOS. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get POI icons you need to use Places API for [Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android/) and [iOS](https://developers.google.com/places/ios/?hl=en)

You can not customize the icon from these API.

Only way I see that you can customize POI icon is over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269231/google-maps-api-v3-point-of-interest-with-custom-icons) using custom marker